# rigorous terminology for coordinate space equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra

in a linear algebra class i was given a theorem: If $\left\{\boldsymbol{u}_{1}, \boldsymbol{u}_{2}, \ldots, \boldsymbol{u}_{n}\right\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then
$
\mathbb{R}^{n}=\operatorname{span}\left\{\boldsymbol{u}_{1}, \boldsymbol{u}_{2}, \ldots, \boldsymbol{u}_{n}\right\}
$

I understand what this means but it got me thinking - what do we really mean when we say a set is equal to  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? If we have the two vectors (1,0,0) and (0,1,0), then they are linearly independent and their span gives us a plane. Now, would we call this spanning set equal to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ or is it just isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? If we only have the latter, then is any subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ actually equal to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ or can we only talk about a set being equal to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ when we have not explicitly defined vectors that can live in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ (as in vectors that have 3 coordinates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their span is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$, and specifically it is $V=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\,:\, z=0\}$. An isomorphism $V\to \Bbb R^2$ could be, for instance, the restriction to $V$ of the map $(x,y,z)\to (x,y)$.

---

Some authors adopt the (completely arbitrary, in my opinion) convention of having $\Bbb R^n$ conventionally embedded in the subspace $\{(x_1,\cdots, x_n,x_{n+1})\,:\, x_{n+1}\}\subseteq \Bbb R^n$, and therefore in such context I presume one should assume all the $\Bbb R^n$-s to be subspaces of $$\Bbb R^{(\Bbb N_{\ge1})}:=\{(x_i\,:\,i\ge 1)\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N_{\ge1}}\,:\, \exists m\in \Bbb N,\forall n\ge m,\ x_n=0\}$$ and specifically $\Bbb R^n=\{(x_i\,:\,i\ge1)\in\Bbb R^{(\Bbb N_{\ge1})}\,:\, \forall m>n,\ x_m=0\}$. Such convention should include an overhaul of notation where one calls the sequence $(x,y,0,0,\cdots)$ different names depending on whether it is seen as an element of $\Bbb R^2$, $\Bbb R^3$, $\Bbb R^4$ et cetera: respectively, one would call it $(x,y)$ when he wants to stress the fact that it is in $\Bbb R^2$, $(x,y,0)$ when  it's in $\Bbb R^3$, $(x,y,0,0)$ when it's in $\Bbb R^4$ and so on. With all this beloved machinery, one could finally achieve the possibility of making the confusing statement $\Bbb R^2=\operatorname{span}((1,0,0),(0,1,0))$.

Answer (score 1):

See the span of the vectors you mentioned is isomorphic to $\mathbb {R}^2$, similarly any two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb {R}^2$.

We identify $\mathbb {R}^2$ inside $\mathbb {R}^3$ with the subspace of $\mathbb {R}^3$ consisting of  the vectors having last coordinate 0.

This isomorphisms of two dimensional subspaces depends on embedding as in how you will consider them inside $\mathbb {R}^3$. [you can think of any plane passing through origin.] So, they are not canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb {R}^2$ but as vector space they are isomorphic to $\mathbb {R}^2$.